# parse.com displaying and editing user details

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

i am using parse.com with a standard user class with extra columns. i.e. address 1,2, and 3

i want to use a view controller that will display the contents from the current user and the address details will be blank until user fills them in then it would save the correct place after a save button press

now i have tried a view controller with textfields and now I'm trying a table view which dosnt look very nice hence view controller . but i can't seem to get any to pull the details in to the text fields. has anyone got any ideas how i can do this

any online tuts or example i can use. i have tried posting this to parse but my post has been up for nearly a week and i posted again 2 days ago and no one seems to answer
link to parse post https://parse.com/questions/fill-a-view-controller-with-my-user-details-to-edit-and-add-more-info

thanks in advance

i am using Xcode 5 DP2 and iOS 7.1 SDK

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:currentUser];
NSArray *userDetails = [query findObjects];

UserNameText.text = objectForKey@"username";
EmailAddressText.text = objectForKey@"email";





}
```

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>


@interface UserEditViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserNameText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *EmailAddressText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *MobileText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Address1Text;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Address2Text;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PostCodeText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TaxiOrCust;


- (IBAction)SaveBtn:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)RestePasswordBtn:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Please post code that shows what you are trying, but is not working.

Comment: check update the parse.com website really dosnt cover retrieving and displaying user details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currentUser` of `PFUser` is a Parse Object with all the properties you have set, there's no need to do a query to get it/them.

The main things that are different about the PFUser class are detailed in [the guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS), specifically you should only create them using the supplied `signUp` method.

Any changes you make to the current user, you can simply call the `save` method.

Comment: but i want and need a users profile page so the details can be changed. so i will need to drag the info already there and be able to change it if needed. i have read the info in the link over and over and nothing covers dragging the info in to a view controller

Comment: @MikeAsp Once you have `currentUser`, you can use it just like any other Parse Object, so the examples that cover editing any object apply. At that point, it is no different to doing it with anything else.

Comment: so why is it just retuning 4 of the 8 colums that i have i have address in there and more just it just returns the basic details username password email and a null

Comment: That's an entirely different question, and valid reason to create a new question if it hasn't already been asked. Try doing `[[PFUser currentUser] refresh]` first though, just in case your cache doesn't have everything.